# How to refresh application launcher after enabling / disabling an activity-alias?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest

I made an application with this manifest

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.example.AliasIcon"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:targetActivity="com.example.Activity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
</application>
```

since the application does not need a launcher I would like to to display the application once and letting the user choose whether to keep or hide the icon

In the code I wrote

```
showIcon = hideIcon.isChecked();
    componentIcon = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), "com.example.AliasIcon");

    if (showIcon){
        flagIcon = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
    }else{
        flagIcon = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
    }


    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentIcon, flagIcon, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    hideIcon.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

showIcon is boolean, hideIcon is a CheckBox, componentIcon is ComponentName, flagIcon is int.

when I run the application (emulator on api8) everything works but the icon does not disappear. 
If I click appears a toast that says "application not installed". 
To make it disappear I have to restart the emulator.

Is there a way to "update" the application launcher?
Maybe using android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED

Comment: For me it was possible to just enable and disable again a fake component from my manifest. The same way as you enable an activity alias, just with a receiver or somethign similar to force the broadcast "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED". That forced my launcher to update. Maybe it helps you too.